# Prior art request: crane arms

Tags: prior-art-request, ep1889808b1, crane-arm

In reference to the European patent EP1889808B1, available in Lens [EP1889808B1](https://www.lens.org/lens/patent/EP_1889808_B1) and in Google Patents [EP1889808B1](https://patents.google.com/patent/EP1889808B1/en?oq=EP1889808B1).

**Claim:**
A crane arm having a fixing device for working implements, wherein the fixing device has rotary joints spaced along a vertical axis with a rotary joint at the crane arm side and a rotary joint at the working implement side in the manner of a cardan joint whose axes of rotation are arranged perpendicularly to each other, wherein hose lines lead from the crane arm to connections to a rotator arranged between the working implement and the rotary joint at the working implement side and wherein the rotary joint at the crane arm side has two spaced rotary bearings along its axis of rotation and the hose lines lead from the crane arm to the connections between the two rotary bearings **characterised in that** the connections (8) for the hose lines (7) are arranged at the side (1a) of the fixing device (2), that is towards the crane arm (1) and the hose lines (7) pass the rotary joint shifted in the direction of the axis of rotation of the rotary joint at the working implement side.

Comment: If you would link to an English version of the patent it would help.

Comment: Thanks! That's interesting. I linked it to the English version, but it still directs to German version.  For English version you need to click in right side menu on  "Other languages: English".

Comment: I changed the link to an equivalent on on The Lens. I find The Lens generally more reliable than any Google site for patent searching. You also might try editing the claims using the quoting tool to be easier to read.

Comment: Very good :) but Lens, I guess, in this case has only claim in English and full text is in German. Regarding the Google Patent link, it seems that Google has made some changes, but I think I managed to link it to English version (which is automatic translation) now.